# react visualize re-rendering/ updating elements

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering thousands of svg elements using react, and want to make sure that minimal rendering is done in case of change in input. sometimes a single node is updated, and since I don't do any `shouldComponentUpdate`, it should be re rendering all the elements. I wonder is there a package available to visualize the changes. I see two packages

https://github.com/redsunsoft/react-render-visualizer

https://github.com/spredfast/react-transform-render-visualizer

but what I am really after is how it is done in this article

[image]
http://blog.atom.io/2014/07/02/moving-atom-to-react.html

how can it be done? any package available?

Comment: Not visualization, but yells at you in the console: https://github.com/garbles/why-did-you-update

Answer (score 7):

There is a setting in Chrome's DevTools that provides a very similar visualization called [Show paint rectangles](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings) or [Paint Flashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas). Go to DevTools and hit the escape key on your keyboard. Go to the rendering tab in the panel that appears and choose "Show paint rectangles" or "Paint Flashing":

[image]